# Team Foundation Server 2017 and c++ .lib files

Tags: c++

I have c++ project with references to another dll project which generates .lib file.

Local on my machine i provide path in property "Additional Library Directories" on first project where to search for .lib file generated by my second dll project.

But for server this path set in "additional library directories" property isn't valid since there are different locations on server and the build fails because .lib file cannot be found.

So i want to know how do you set linker options of c++ projects for team foundation server. More specifically how to solve this .lib link problem?

Comment: (a) relative paths. Or (b) an environment variable that is the root of your development tree (eg $(DEV_ROOT)) and reference all paths based from it.

Comment: You can try to add a `Copy task` to copy the  .lib file to the correct path for reference.

Comment: Isn't property "Link Library Dependencies" set to "Yes" supposed to automatically link lib files of referenced projects?

Comment: @Igor You can have a try with that. Basically the "Additional Library Directories" should be absolute path, So as Richard mentiond, you need to specify a relative path or a shared folder which the build agent service account can access it.  Alternatively as I mentioned above you can add a `copy step` to copy the  generated .lib file to the correct path for reference.  This article may helps: [Managing Source Control Dependencies in Visual Studio Team System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668956.aspx)